# Processing Less CSS files that have php tags

Tags: php, less, gruntjs

We have a less file `hi_style.less`:

```
@import "css/base-ui.less";

#hi {
    margin: 100px;
}
```

that includes another less file `css/base-ui.less` with lines like this:

```
.ui-go {
    background: #74A372 url(<?php echo $l_uri; ?>/images/ui-go.png) repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
}
```

The reason we need php (unless someone has a better idea) is because there is only one codebase but we have many sites attached to separate database from that singular codebase.

e.g.

`site-a.mysite.com` and `site-b.mysite.com` both use the same code but the urls are obviously different.

Is there a way to ignore the php tags in less or a better way to have explicit urls with one codebase.

We can't use relative paths as the base path can change and point to a different codebase.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: It can't be a static file after it's processed because the codebases can be accessed via a url like: `site-a.mysite.com/testing` or `site-a.mysite.com/beta` so the url of the image file could be:

`http://site-a.mysite.com/images/ui-go.png` or

`http://site-a.mysite.com/testing/images/ui-go.png` or

`http://site-a.mysite.com/beta/images/ui-go.png` depending upon the codebase that's being accessed.

Comment: Cache this file locally (e.g. in `site-a.mysite.com/css/base-ui.less`) instead of using the file with php code in it every time. You can process this (now valid) file however you want. You can update this cached file every few hours or so, or how you see fit. This will increase performance too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that wrapping the `url` string in quote marks ([which is quite valid](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri); here I did single quotes `'`) will solve your issue. So...

```css
.ui-go {
    background: #74A372 url('<?php echo $l_uri; ?>/images/ui-go.png') repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
}
```

That allows LESS to actually output the string with the php code (rather than throw an error), then when you run your *compiled* css through the php parser (I assume that is what you are doing), it should still fill in the `echo` value as needed.